# Linear Regression with variables as columns in R

Tags: r, variables, regression

My objective is to get variables (column names in this case) from Python, and then process them in R. When i try to perform Linear Regression such as:

```
cropeareatable<-matrix(c(111111,222222,333333,2222222),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(cropeareatable)<-c('Canola_RE','Canola_CI')
cropeareatable

x<-(colnames(cropeareatable))
re <-x[0]
ci<-x[1]
linreg<-lm(table$re~table$ci)
```

EDIT: changed to be reproducable

Error recieved:Error in table$re : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

It  does not work. I have looked into it, and have tried many different approaches

do.call

```
regress<-do.call(rlm,list(cropareatable[3],cropareatable[4]),quote=FALSE)
regress<-do.call(rlm,list(x[3],y[4]),quote=FALSE)
```

quote()+eval:

```
x<-(colnames(cropareatable))
    re <-quote(x[3])
    ci<-quote(x[4])
    linreg<-lm(table$eval(re)~table$eval(ci))
```

I have also tried formula-building,dataframe building,as.list,but I have not been able to get the regression to work at all.

Comment: Please try and make this reproducible.  Also, what error are you receiving?  Particularly in your first code block.

Comment: I have simplified it down ,and it is not reproducible.The error is also displayed.

Comment: `table$re : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` is probably just because `table` is a built-in function.  Consider using a different variable name.

Comment: Ah -- I think I see it; you want to specify the columns by name.  The `$` operator is pretty much just for interactive use.  Consider using `cropeareatable[, ci]` instead for subsetting.

Comment: Wow! thanks alot for this. I was looking all around, and looking into many complicated things, but turns out the best is one is the simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.  First is that `re` and `ci` are being chosen with base index `0`, but R is indexed from `1`.

```
re <- x[1]
ci <- x[2]
```

And then to index, we can use the `[` operator instead of trying to use `$`

```
lm(cropeareatable[, re] ~ cropeareatable[, ci])
```